# Melhor Método para Criar uma Matriz com Múltiplas Linhas Iguais?

Tags: python, numpy

Tenho uma matrix 14x5 e desejo "replicá-la" para que as primeira mil linhas sejam iguais à primeira linha da matriz que já possuo, as próximas mil sejam iguais à segunda das linhas da matrix que já existe e assim por diante, gerando ao final uma matrix 14000x5.
Eu fiz a coisa "na mão" mas fiquei pensando se a matrix fosse 5000x5. Além de quase impraticável fica "feio" demais no código.

```
    memory =  np.vstack((susc_seade, expo_seade, assi_referencia, sint_seade, recu_assumido))
    memory = np.transpose(memory)
    rows, columns = np.shape(memory)
    matrix_memory = np.zeros([int(rows/dt - 1/dt), columns])    
    for i in range((int(rows/dt))):
        for j in range(5):
            if i >=0 and i<= 1000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[1,j]
            if i >=1001 and i<= 2000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[2,j]
            if i >=2001 and i<= 3000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[3,j]               
            if i >=3001 and i<= 4000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[4,j]    
            if i >=4001 and i<= 5000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[5,j]                
            if i >=5001 and i<= 6000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[6,j]        
            if i >=6001 and i<= 7000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[7,j]
            if i >=7001 and i<= 8000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[8,j]               
            if i >=8001 and i<= 9000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[9,j]               
            if i >=9001 and i<= 10000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[10,j]               
            if i >=10001 and i<= 11000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[11,j]
            if i >=11001 and i<= 12000:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[12,j]
            if i >=12001 and i<= 12999:
               matrix_memory[i,j] = memory[13,j] 
    return matrix_memory
```

No código, memory é a matrix 14x5, dt= 0.001 e matrix_memory é a matrix 14000x5 que desejo gerar.

Comment: Se uma matriz é 5x14, então ela possui 5 linhas e 14 colunas. De onde você pegaria as "*primeiras **mil** linhas*"?

Comment: Woss, acho que não fui muito claro. Deixe-me tentar explicar melhor: seja A a matrix 14x5 que eu tenho. Eu desejo, a partir dela, construir uma matrix B cujas primeiras mil linhas sejam idênticas à primeira linha de A, as próximas mil linhas sejam idênticas à segunda linha de A e assim por adiante. Acho que agora ficou mais claro! Obrigado por tentar entender meu problema e me ajudar.

Comment: Pelo visto uma simples operação matemática resolveria aí: `i // 1000 + 1`, pega a parte inteira da divisão de `i` por 1000 e soma 1. Assim, qualquer valor menor que 1000 tem a divisão igual a 0, que somando 1 fica 1; qualquer valor menor que 2000 tem a divisão igual a 1, que somando 1 fica 2 e por aí vai. Talvez você precisaria tratar os casos limites, 1000, 2000, etc, que a divisão cairia no próximo valor, mas dado que você comentou que quer as "primeiras mil linhas", não faz sentido tratar de 0 a 1000, inclusive, como iguais, pois seriam 1001 linhas.

Comment: Entendi! Realmente a minha conta de 1000 linhas em cada caso está errada. Estou incluindo 1001 linhas. Acabeide corrigir isso e vou usar sua sugestão. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se procura repetir elementos de um array ou matriz [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) uma solução pode ser obtida usando a função [`numpy.repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat).

A função `numpy.repeat()` repete os elementos de um array ou matriz ao longo de um eixo. No exemplo a baixo cada linha do array `m` será replicada por cinco vezes:

```
import numpy as np

#Declara o array m cujo as dimensões 3x4.
m = np.array([
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12]
])

#Gera um novo array de dimensões 15x4 preenchido com 5 repetições de cada  linha de m.
print(np.repeat(m, 5, axis=0))
#[[ 1  2  3  4]
# [ 1  2  3  4]
# [ 1  2  3  4]
# [ 1  2  3  4]
# [ 1  2  3  4]
# [ 5  6  7  8]
# [ 5  6  7  8]
# [ 5  6  7  8]
# [ 5  6  7  8]
# [ 5  6  7  8]
# [ 9 10 11 12]
# [ 9 10 11 12]
# [ 9 10 11 12]
# [ 9 10 11 12]
# [ 9 10 11 12]]
```

<sup>Teste a solução no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/mrepeat#main.py)</sup>

Aplicando a solução acima ao seu exemplo deve ficar algo assim:

```
memory =  np.vstack((susc_seade, expo_seade, assi_referencia, sint_seade, recu_assumido))
memory = np.transpose(memory)
#Retorna uma matriz de dimensões 14000x5 repetindo 1000 vezes cada linha de memory.
return np.repeat(memory, 1000, axis=0)
```

Comment: Augusto, ajudou demais! Python sempre tem um jeito elegante pra coisas acontecerem. É incrível. Obrigado novamente! :)